# Symbolicate command not found when fully symbolicate the crash report in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I get this error when I submit App to AppStore:

[image]

I searched the net and found this article: https://jmillerdev.com/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/

I tried to follow the step-by-step instructions as follows:

1. I downloaded the crashlog.txt files and changed the extension to .crash, moved it to the **folder CrashTop**
2. I found the .app file by changing MyApp.ipa to MyApp.zip and extracting it. It's in the **folder PayLoad**. I copied the file MyApp.iOS to the **folder CrashTop**
3. In Xcode/Window/Organizer. Archives Show in Finder opens showing the package contents. I found the dSYMs folder and copied the .dSYM file to the **folder CrashTop**

Next i Open Terminal and run this command:

```
alias symbolicate="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v"
```

and

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

**Run Symbolicate**

Open Terminal again and `cd` to the directory **folder CrashTop** and run the command

```
symbolicate -o "symbolicatedCrash.txt" "crashlog-DCE8F822-47EB-42F9-A737-5D137FD827FE.crash" "MyApp.iOS.app"
```

But what I get back is: `command not found: symbolicate`

It's been 10 days. I've tried searching all over the internet. But it doesn't solve the problem. I also used Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes to catch the error. However, it shows no errors. On xcode (13.3.1) simulator it works fine.

Please solution to solve this problem.
Ask for any help from everyone.

**Update**

- Copy all files to CrashTop folder.

[image]

- Run command:

  ```
  export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
  ```

and

```
./symbolicatecrash -v crashlog-DCE8F822-47EB-42F9-A737-5D137FD827FE.crash MyApp.iOS.app.dSYM
```

-> I get the error: **zsh: no such file or directory: ./symbolicatecrash**

Answer (score 0):

Do not set alias  .

You can copy `symbolicatecrash` file and paste it to the CrashTop  folder .

and run the command

```
./symbolicatecrash -v MyApp-Crash-log.crash MyApp.dSYM
```

Comment: I get the error: zsh: no such file or directory: ./symbolicatecrash. I updated the above, you can watch it

Comment: I get the error: `zsh: command not found: symbolicatecrash` :(

Comment: I see you copy `symbolicatecrash ` file but it is a `txt` file , it should  be an `Executable` file .

Comment: And `./symbolicatecrash` command is correct , I just tried on my mac.

Comment: How did you create the symbolicatecrash file?

Comment: Find the file in path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash` , copy and paste it to `CrashTop ` folder.